# Scrivener for Vim?

Tags: large-documents

I really enjoy the workflow in [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php), but I don't like the non-vim nature of it. Is there a good alternative plugin for vim that let's you manage documents in a similar way? I'm most interested in the ability to sort and compile documents.

My goal would be to have the ability to edit a document in multiple parts. I'm imagining something like NerdTree, but with the ability to vertically rearrange files in an arbitrary way. It is important that the files are ultimately compiled down into a single document. I imagine that this could be done with Pandoc, but I don't know how well integrated that may be. It would be really slick if there was a way to simply append certain documents together and have that save as a new file.

A couple people have thought about this sort of thing before:

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/179648-vim-writers-scrivener-replacement.html

https://parezcoydigo.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/vim-scrivener/

Comment: Since this is asking for plugin recommendations, please do follow [softwarerecs.se]'s [guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) - specifically: "even if you're asking for alternatives, we need to know which features you need." I have no idea what Scrivener is, and may be someone here who hasn't used Scrivener but uses a similar plugin would be lost as well. Also see: http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/118/205

Comment: Good links -- thanks for pointing them out. I'll try to refactor my question so that it better matches the recommendations you linked to.

Comment: It's not entirely sure to me what exactly you're looking for, perhaps that's because I've never used Scrivener. "Edit a document in multiple parts" can be done by simply have several files in a directory. "Compiling" them to a single document is simply appending them all to one document, and rearranging files can be done my renaming them (e.g. you could prefix them with a number: `10-introduction`, `20-first-chapter`, etc.)

Comment: Definitely true, and I've used some of those options in the past, but they've always been pretty clunky. It's a hassle to figure out name changes if you've got a lot of parts, and compiling them also seems like a manual process. Since it sounds like there's nothing like this available, I'll probably close this question in a bit. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe [microviche plugin](https://github.com/q335r49/microviche) can be useful, check also [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YNiPUTGO28)